# A sigsev error (runtime) that I can't seem to understand

Tags: c++, runtime-error, c++14

So I was submitting this code on an online judge, while the code is running fine on my system it gives me this error for the same input on the Online Judge.

```
    GDB trace:
Reading symbols from solution...done.
[New LWP 4622]
Core was generated by `solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl::_Vector_impl (
    this=0x7ffe815275a0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:89
89      : _Tp_alloc_type(), _M_start(), _M_finish(), _M_end_of_storage()
#0  std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl::_Vector_impl (
    this=0x7ffe815275a0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:89
#1  std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_base (
    this=0x7ffe815275a0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:127
#2  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector (this=0x7ffe815275a0)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:263
#3  main () at solution.cc:8
```

Since the contest is live I am not sure about sharing my code but if anyone has some idea about this error it would be very helpful.

Note that the error is caused for the exactly same input on Cpp 14.

Ok so I have decided to share my code:

[code](https://ideone.com/0Nqd1J)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n],b[n];
    int max=1000000;
    vector<int> c1[max+1],c2[max+1];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
        c1[a[i]].push_back(a[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>b[i];
        c2[b[i]].push_back(b[i]);
    }
    for(int i=max;i>=1;i--){
        //cout<<i<<endl;
        int f1=0,f2=0;
        for(int j=i;j<=max;j+=i){
            if(c1[j].size()>0){
                f1=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int j=i;j<=max;j+=i){
            if(c2[j].size()>0){
                f2=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(f1 && f2){
            int max1=0,max2=0;
            for(int j=i;j<=max;j+=i){
                if(c1[j].size()){
                    for(int k=0;k<c1[j].size();k++){
                        if(max1<c1[j][k])
                            max1=c1[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int j=i;j<=max;j+=i){
                if(c2[j].size()){
                    for(int k=0;k<c2[j].size();k++){
                        if(max2<c2[j][k])
                            max2=c2[j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
            cout<<max1+max2;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Since this was downvoted I just want to know why? How could I have asked this question in a better way?

Comment: Does this "online judge" generate downloadable debugging symbols & core dump?

Comment: @zv_ No debugging symbols are generated.

Comment: It would help to post your relevant code, to even have a change to tell what's wrong.

Comment: @Maikel shared it

Comment: `int a[n],b[n];` are VLA's, which are not part of the c++ standard. The online judge compiler may not support it, while ideone supports it.

Comment: `vector<int> c1[max+1],c2[max+1];` is plainly wrong and does not what you want to. Use `vector<int> c1(max+1); vector<int> c2(max+1);` instead.

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: It doesn't explain why you get a segmentation fault though. This is always a bug, but it is not clear to me if it affects ideone or gcc itself.

Comment: @MichaelWalz the one in the ideone link

Comment: @Maikel OP uses `c1` and `c2` as arrays of vectors: `c1[a[i]].push_back(a[i]);`, so the declaration matches the usage.

Comment: @mch I see, my bad.

Comment: @Maikel I want to declare an array of vectors, doing that would give me a compilation error

Comment: "Running fine on my system" often indicates an incomplete set of test cases.

Comment: @TobySpeight that's why I added the note, it was on the same test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you're running out of stack space - stick to `vector`.
(Variable-length arrays are non-standard. Don't use them.)

Changing the declarations should be enough:

```
vector<int> a(n),b(n);
int max=1000000;
vector<vector<int>> c1(max+1), c2(max+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare an array of vectors, I would recommend using the array container class. The only thing you have to keep in mind is that `max` needs to be `const` for this to work.

```
const int max = 1000000;
std::array<std::vector<int, max + 1> c1, c2;
```

I prefer this solution over the "classic" vector of vectors in any case where the size of the array is known at compile time since it is IMO easier on the eye.

Comment: Unfortunately, a `std::array` takes up just as much space as a regular array, so you're just as sensitive to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace leaves your code at line 8, so that's the first place to look:

```
vector<int> c1[max+1],c2[max+1];
```

Given that `max` is 1000000, you're trying to create two million and two vectors in local storage.  It's not surprising that this fails - most implementations use a stack for local storage, with a sensible maximum size.  You'll want to create these using `new`, or (better) `std::make_unique()`.

As for `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` - you really want to drop those bad habits, which are particularly harmful when used together.